# Information on RS232 interface commands for Motorola's RS507

Tags: serial-port, motorola

Anyone know where I'd get information on the RS232 interface commands for [Motorola's RS507
Ring Scanner](http://www.motorola.com/Business/US-EN/Business+Product+and+Services/Mobile+Computers/Wearable+Computers/RS507_US-EN)?

I've managed to set up a serial port and connect using Putty. On opening the port I get the "^E" enquiry character. On return I get "Ñþ©". On trigger I get "ö þåö!þä"

I want to look for a barcode on trigger.

Cheers

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! It uses Motorola's standard SSI commands

http://www.motorola.com/web/Business/Products/Bar%20Code%20Scanning/Bar%20Code%20Scanners/Fixed%20Mount%20Scanners/MiniScan%20954/_Documents/Static%20Files/5986003a.pdf